# How to create a unique reference for the result each time?

Tags: python, django

In general, I make a page on the site. The meaning is this: a person comes in, loads an xml file, selects several parameters, and outputs the result. I did not find how to handle the xml file at once. So I upload its file with the parameters to the database, and then redirect us to the page with the result. Everything works fine, but there is a problem. I have not figured out how to create a unique link for the result each time. Now I have one link for the results and it just shows the last one ...
views.py of uploader

```
def upload_file(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('lessons:index')
else:
    form = DocumentForm()
return render(request, 'templates/upload/upload.html', {'form': form})
 downloader
```

views.py of handler

```
def lessons_view(request):

        a = keker()

        return render(request, 'templates/lessons/ocenki.html', {'ocenki': a})
```

keker if handler function

Comment: If the `DocumentForm` is a `ModelForm`, then you already have one: the `id` of the `Document` that is generated. Optionally you can hash it, such that people can *not* exhaustively see other `Document`s.

Comment: My DocumentForm is a ModelForm. Maybe i can send pk nor something else here:return redirect('lessons:index')?

Comment: Well it looks to me you probably want to redirect to the correct `lessons_view` immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code like this (python 3.6):

```
# models.py
class Document(Model):
  ...
  reference = CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True, null=False)
  ...  

# forms.py
import secrets
...
class DocumentForm(ModelForm):
  ...
  def save(self, commit=True):
    self.instance.reference = secrets.token_hex(128)
    return super().save(commit)

# views.py
...
def upload_file(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      return redirect('lessons:index', kwargs=dict(reference=form.instance.reference))
  else:
    form = DocumentForm()
 return render(request, 'templates/upload/upload.html', {'form': form})

...
def lessons_view(request, reference):
    a = keker(reference)
    return render(request, 'templates/lessons/ocenki.html', {'ocenki': a})

# urls.py
...
url(r'^/(?P<reference>\w+)/$', 'index', name='index'),
...
```

Comment: Try reduce size of token `secrets.token_hex(16)`

Comment: Have you rewrite urls rule? Show your urls patterns

Comment: i change this url(r'^/(?P<reference>\w+)/$', 'index', name='index') to this url(r'^/(?P<reference>\w+)/$', lessons_view, name='index'),

Comment: Give me application name (python package name) of urls.py file specified above. I see you have `main` and `upload` packages. You should rewrite urls pattern to **pass reference to view function**. I don't know your project structure and urls patterns

Comment: You have Django 2.x installed, you can use more easy notation for configure urls https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/

Comment: Thank you so much! I just changed this return redirect('lessons:index', kwargs=dict(reference=form.instance.reference)) to this return redirect('lessons:index', reference=form.instance.reference). And it works! 
My url looks like that 
path('<reference>', lessons.lessons_view, name='index'),